# Ejebberd error message when set stream_management config

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I'm receive this error in ejabberd error.log:
"2016-08-23 04:18:48.260 [error] <0.1622.0>@ejabberd_config:validate_opts:940 unknown option 'ack' will be likely ignored"
Does anyone know what this message?
I think this error mesage acquired when i set below config:
stream_management: true
resend_on_timeout: true

Comment: Can i use this module: https://github.com/johanvorster/ejabberd_confirm_delivery

Answer (score 0):

This error resolve when i fix host_config in ejabberd.yml
Thanks a lot.